# Validation on image pixel

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Angular js Image upload how to check width and height example my withd=200 and heidht =200 if give more than pixel its show be error how can i us it if i try some thing can solve it

**HTML**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label">Logo :</label>
    <div class="col-sm-4">
        <input filestyle="" type="file" name="file" required="" ng-model="form.logo" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().add(this.files).checkPhoto(this)" accept="image/jpeg,image/jpg" data-classbutton="btn btn-default" data-classinput="form-control inline" class="form-control" />
        <br><label Style="color: Red;">Logo should be in (550 X 150) size</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$scope.fileList1 = [];
$scope.add1 = function(file1) {
    console.log(file1);
    for (var i = 0; i < file1.length; i++) {
        if (file1[i].type == 'image/jpeg' || file1[i].type == 'image/jpg' || file1[i].type == 'image/tif' || file1[i].type == 'image/tiff') {
            var item = {
                name: file1[i].name,
                file: file1[i]
            };
            $scope.fileList1.push(item);
            var f = file1[i],
                r = new FileReader();
            console.log($scope.fileList1);
            r.onloadend = function(e) {
            }
            r.readAsDataURL(f);
        } else {
            $('#file1').val('');
            Notify.alert('Upload only .jpeg,jpg,tiff,tif format file', {
                status: 'warning',
                pos: 'top-right',
                timeout: 3000
            });
        }
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use ng-flow (a library to upload file on AngularJS), and check image dimension in its flow-file-added/flow-files-added handler.

Here is an example by AidasK: https://github.com/flowjs/ng-flow/issues/126